# Resolving errors trying to assign values to range variables in Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, reference, range

I am writing a procedure to generate a number of named ranges from values in a worksheet, with the cell to be named in column C and the name to be assigned in the adjacent cell in column D. All variations I've tried to reference these two cells as ranges returned errors. While this procedure will be used only once to generate these names, I'd like to determine the correct syntax so I'll be able to reference ranges for other purposes in the future.

I have a temporary ActiveX CommandButton that calls the following code (just referencing two rows for now for testing purposes):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call SetRangeNames(38, 39)
End Sub
```

I placed the SetRangeNames procedure in a module based on recommendations in posts I've seen elsewhere. The two lines of code returning errors are indicated by a comment within the procedure code, and all of the variations I've tried (with the errors they return) follow that. I placed a MsgBox call in the proc to see how it was rendering the cell references generated. It displays:

```
rangeNameValueCellAddress = "C38"; namedRangeCellAddress = "D38"
```

or

```
rangeNameValueCellAddress = "C39"; namedRangeCellAddress = "D39"
```

Here's one varation of the proc:

```
Public Sub SetRangeNames(startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer)
    Dim theRange As Range
    Dim currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentName As String
    Dim rangeNameValueCellAddress As String
    Dim namedRangeCellAddress As String

    For currentRow = startRow To endRow
        rangeNameValueCellAddress = """D" & Trim(Str(currentRow) & """")
        namedRangeCellAddress = """C" & Trim(Str(currentRow) & """")
        MsgBox ("rangeNameValueCellAddress = " & rangeNameValueCellAddress & _
            "; namedRangeCellAddress = " & namedRangeCellAddress)
        'MsgBox displays: rangeNameValueCellAddress = "C38"; namedRangeCellAddress = "D38"
        ' or: rangeNameValueCellAddress = "C39"; namedRangeCellAddress = "D39"
        '*** The following two statements return errors:
        Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet).Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
        currentName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet).Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=currentName, RefersTo:=theRange
    Next currentRow
End Sub
```

Here are the variations I tried ("SYSProjectData" is both the name and CodeName and Name of the worksheet I am working with):

```
Set theRange = SYSProjectData.Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = SYSProjectData.Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.SYSProjectData.Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = ThisWorkbook.SYSProjectData.Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

```
Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Set theRange = ActiveSheet.Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = ActiveSheet.Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SYSProjectData).Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SYSProjectData).Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Type mismatch"

```
Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SYSProjectData").Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SYSProjectData").Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SYSProjectData).Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SYSProjectData).Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Type mismatch"

```
Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SYSProjectData").Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SYSProjectData").Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet).Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Type mismatch"

```
Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet).Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
currentName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet).Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2
```

Returns: "Type mismatch"

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Public Sub SetRangeNames(startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer)

    Dim currentRow As Long 'Long not Integer (always safer)

    For currentRow = startRow To endRow

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SYSProjectData")
            'worksheets Parent is the containing workbook
            .Parent.Names.Add Name:=.Cells(currentRow, "D"), _
                                     RefersTo:=.Cells(currentRow, "C")
        End With

    Next currentRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres your code, commented where there are issues

```
'Public Sub SetRangeNames(startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer)
'    Better to use Long
Public Sub SetRangeNames(startRow As Long, endRow As Long)

    Dim theRange As Range
    Dim currentRow As Long ' Integer
    Dim currentName As String
    Dim rangeNameValueCellAddress As String
    Dim namedRangeCellAddress As String

    For currentRow = startRow To endRow
        'rangeNameValueCellAddress = """D" & Trim(Str(currentRow) & """")
        '  Don't include " in the string value.
        '  No need for Trim(Str(
        rangeNameValueCellAddress = "D" & currentRow

        'namedRangeCellAddress = """C" & Trim(Str(currentRow) & """")
        namedRangeCellAddress = "C" & currentRow

        MsgBox ("rangeNameValueCellAddress = " & rangeNameValueCellAddress & _
            "; namedRangeCellAddress = " & namedRangeCellAddress)
        '*** The following two statements return errors:

        'Set theRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet).Range(namedRangeCellAddress)
        '  ActiveSheet is already a worksheetsheet
        Set theRange = ActiveSheet.Range(namedRangeCellAddress)

        currentName = ActiveSheet.Range(rangeNameValueCellAddress).Value2

        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=currentName, RefersTo:=theRange
    Next currentRow
End Sub
```

Here's an alternate method, see inline comments

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    SetRangeNames2 ActiveSheet.Range("C8")
End Sub

Public Sub SetRangeNames2(startCell As Range)
    Dim Nm As Name
    Dim Dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With startCell.Worksheet
        ' Copy data to Variant array, for speed
        Dat = .Range(startCell, .Cells(.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2).Value2

        '  Loop the array
        For i = 1 To UBound(Dat, 1)
            ' Check if name already exists
            Set Nm = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
            Set Nm = .Names(Dat(i, 2))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Nm Is Nothing Then
                ' Add name
                .Parent.Names.Add Name:=Dat(i, 2), RefersTo:=.Range(Dat(i, 1))
            Else
                ' Name Already exists, update it
                Nm.RefersToRange = .Range(Dat(i, 1))
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in posting this. This is what I ended up with...

```
Public Sub SetRangeNames(strNamedRangeColumn As String, strNameSourceColumn As String, startRow As Long, endRow As Long)
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim rngNameSourceCell As Range
    Dim rngNamedRangeCell As Range
    Dim strNameSourceCellAddress As String
    Dim strNamedRangeCellAddress As String
    Dim strNameSourceCellValue As String
    Dim strNamedRangeCellValue As String
    Dim strRangeValueError As String

    strRangeValueError = ""
    strNamedRangeColumn = Trim(UCase(strNamedRangeColumn))
    strNameSourceColumn = Trim(UCase(strNameSourceColumn))

    If Len(strNamedRangeColumn) > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("ERROR: The value given for the named range column, """ & strNamedRangeColumn & _
            ","" was longer than one character.")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Len(strNameSourceColumn) > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("ERROR: The value given for the name source column, """ & strNameSourceColumn & _
            ","" was longer than one character.")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf strNamedRangeColumn = "" Then
        MsgBox ("ERROR: The value given for the named range column was longer than one character.")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf strNameSourceColumn = "" Then
        MsgBox ("ERROR: The value given for the name source column was longer than one character.")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Asc(strNamedRangeColumn) < 65 Or Asc(strNamedRangeColumn) > 90 Then
        MsgBox ("ERROR: The value given for the named range column, """ & strNamedRangeColumn & _
            ","" was not a letter.")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Asc(strNameSourceColumn) < 65 Or Asc(strNameSourceColumn) > 90 Then
        MsgBox ("ERROR: The value given for the name source column, """ & strNameSourceColumn & _
            ","" was not a letter.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For currentRow = startRow To endRow
        strNameSourceCellAddress = strNameSourceColumn & Trim(str(currentRow))
        strNamedRangeCellAddress = strNamedRangeColumn & Trim(str(currentRow))
        Set rngNameSourceCell = Range(strNameSourceCellAddress)
        Set rngNamedRangeCell = Range(strNamedRangeCellAddress)

        strNameSourceCellValue = Trim(rngNameSourceCell.Value)

        If IsEmpty(rngNameSourceCell) Or Len(strNameSourceCellValue) > 0 Then
                strRangeValueError = "Source cell " & strNameSourceCellAddress & " was empty."
        End If

        If Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(rngNameSourceCell.Value)) Then
                If Len(strRangeValueError) > 0 Then
                        strRangeValueError = vbCrLf & strRangeValueError
                End If
                strRangeValueError = strRangeValueError & "Source cell " & strNameSourceCellAddress & _
                    " contained the not-text value """ & strNameSourceCellValue & """."
        End If

        If Len(strRangeValueError) > 0 Then
                MsgBox (strRangeValueError)
                Exit Sub
        End If

        ThisWorkbook.sheets("mySheetName").Parent.Names.Add Name:=.Cells(currentRow, strNameSourceColumn), _
            RefersTo:=.Cells(currentRow, strNamedRangeColumn)

    Next currentRow
End Sub
```

Called as follows...

```
Private Sub btnGenerateRangeNames_Click()
    Call SetRangeNames("C", "E", 8, 11)
    ' etc.
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!